# sed append line - how do I get a new line?

Tags: bash, sed

I have spent hours on this but can't crack it. I am using sed on OSX .

This is the code:

```
sed -i.bak "s/^\(\$dokuwiki_hash.*\)$/\1\n    '"$date"'   => '"$hash"',/" install.php
```

And the output that I get which is wrong is (see the first line):

```
$dokuwiki_hash = array(n    '2013-03-17'   => '7b62b75245f57f122d3e0f8ed7989623',
    '2005-09-22'   => 'e33223e957b0b0a130d0520db08f8fb7',
    '2006-03-05'   => '51295727f79ab9af309a2fd9e0b61acc',                                                                                                       
    '2006-03-09'   => '51295727f79ab9af309a2fd9e0b61acc',
    '2006-11-06'   => 'b3a8af76845977c2000d85d6990dd72b',
    '2007-05-24'   => 'd80f2740c84c4a6a791fd3c7a353536f',
    '2007-06-26'   => 'b3ca19c7a654823144119980be73cd77',
    '2008-05-04'   => '1e5c42eac3219d9e21927c39e3240aad',
    '2009-02-14'   => 'ec8c04210732a14fdfce0f7f6eead865',
    '2009-12-25'   => '993c4b2b385643efe5abf8e7010e11f4',
    '2010-11-07'   => '7921d48195f4db21b8ead6d9bea801b8',
    '2011-05-25'   => '4241865472edb6fa14a1227721008072',
    '2011-11-10'   => 'b46ff19a7587966ac4df61cbab1b8b31',
    '2012-01-25'   => '72c083c73608fc43c586901fd5dabb74',
    '2012-09-10'   => 'eb0b3fc90056fbc12bac6f49f7764df3',
    '2013-04-06'   => '7b62b75245f57f122d3e0f8ed7989623',
);
```

It should be on a new line like below:

```
$dokuwiki_hash = array(
    '2013-03-17'   => '7b62b75245f57f122d3e0f8ed7989623',
    '2005-09-22'   => 'e33223e957b0b0a130d0520db08f8fb7',
    '2006-03-05'   => '51295727f79ab9af309a2fd9e0b61acc',                                                                                                       
    '2006-03-09'   => '51295727f79ab9af309a2fd9e0b61acc',
    '2006-11-06'   => 'b3a8af76845977c2000d85d6990dd72b',
    '2007-05-24'   => 'd80f2740c84c4a6a791fd3c7a353536f',
    '2007-06-26'   => 'b3ca19c7a654823144119980be73cd77',
    '2008-05-04'   => '1e5c42eac3219d9e21927c39e3240aad',
    '2009-02-14'   => 'ec8c04210732a14fdfce0f7f6eead865',
    '2009-12-25'   => '993c4b2b385643efe5abf8e7010e11f4',
    '2010-11-07'   => '7921d48195f4db21b8ead6d9bea801b8',
    '2011-05-25'   => '4241865472edb6fa14a1227721008072',
    '2011-11-10'   => 'b46ff19a7587966ac4df61cbab1b8b31',
    '2012-01-25'   => '72c083c73608fc43c586901fd5dabb74',
    '2012-09-10'   => 'eb0b3fc90056fbc12bac6f49f7764df3',
    '2013-04-06'   => '7b62b75245f57f122d3e0f8ed7989623',
);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

Don't use substitute for this, `sed` has a perfectly good append command for adding a line after the current one, without fiddling around with newline or storage of regex results:

```
pax> echo '$dokuwiki_hash = array(
    '"'"'2013-03-17'"'"'   => '"'"'7b62b75245f57f122d3e0f8ed7989623'"'"'
);' | sed '/^\$dokuwiki_hash = /a\    blah '"'"'blah'"'"' blah'
$dokuwiki_hash = array(
    blah 'blah' blah
    '2013-03-17'   => '7b62b75245f57f122d3e0f8ed7989623'
);
```

The machinations with the quotes are to allow you to put literal single quotes within the command.

Alternatively, you can use double quotes on the outside, you just have to be careful that the shell doesn't interpret your dollar-variables:

```
pax> echo "\$dokuwiki_hash = array(
    '2013-03-17'   => '7b62b75245f57f122d3e0f8ed7989623'
);" | sed "/^\$dokuwiki_hash = /a\    blah 'blah' blah"

$dokuwiki_hash = array(
    blah 'blah' blah
    '2013-03-17'   => '7b62b75245f57f122d3e0f8ed7989623'
);
```

There's also an opposing insert command `i` for inserting *before* the current line but it's append you want in this case.

---

And, if you're having trouble with mixing quote types (perhaps due to an older `bash` under OSX), you can put the `sed` commands into a file and use `sed -f` to run them:

```
pax> cat qq.sed

/^$dokuwiki_hash = /a\    blah 'blah' blah

pax> echo '$dokuwiki_hash = array(
    '"'"'2013-03-17'"'"'   => '"'"'7b62b75245f57f122d3e0f8ed7989623'"'"'
);' | sed -f qq.sed

$dokuwiki_hash = array(
    blah 'blah' blah
    '2013-03-17'   => '7b62b75245f57f122d3e0f8ed7989623'
);
```

That gets around any quoting battles between the shell and `sed`. If that *still* doesn't work, see [this link](https://sagebionetworks.jira.com/wiki/plugins/servlet/mobile#content/view/21758014), which suggests installing GNU sed instead.

Comment: I did try 'append' but could not get the single quotes to escape so they would show in the output.

Comment: @ilium007, try the update, I didn't originally take into account nested quotes.

Comment: I keep getting this error "sed: 1: "/^\$dokuwiki_hash = /a\ ...": extra characters after \ at the end of a command"

Comment: Are you _sure_ you're using bash?

Comment: After many years of using UNIX, yes, I am sure I am using bash !

But its a crappy OSX out of date version:

macmini:dokuwiki ilium007$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin12)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
macmini:dokuwiki ilium007$

Comment: You may need to opt for placing your script into a file and using `sed -f` to get round the "primitive" bash version.

Comment: So I am now running:  `GNU bash, version 4.2.45(2)-release (i386-apple-darwin12.2.0)`  And I am still getting:  
`macmini:dokuwiki ilium007$ sed -i .bak '/^\(\$dokuwiki_hash.*\)/a\    blah '"'"'blah'"'"' blah' /Volumes/HDD2/Sites/clients/test/install.php
sed: 1: "/^\(\$dokuwiki_hash.*\) ...": extra characters after \ at the end of a command`

Comment: @ilium007, please enter my code _exactly_ as it is. For example, I have no capture group around the dokuwiki_hash regex. What I've given works fine with bash 4.1.5 and GNU sed 4.2.1. You may want to check your version of sed as well. Otherwise, use the file-based script as per my final code block.

Comment: macmini:dokuwiki ilium007$ cat qq.sed  
/^$dokuwiki_hash = /a\    blah 'blah' blah
macmini:dokuwiki ilium007$ echo '$dokuwiki_hash = array(
>     '"'"'2013-03-17'"'"'   => '"'"'7b62b75245f57f122d3e0f8ed7989623'"'"'
> );' | sed -f qq.sed
sed: 1: qq.sed: extra characters after \ at the end of a command
macmini:dokuwiki ilium007$

Comment: Check the sed version. If it too is "primitive" like bash was, consider upgrading, or just installing gnu sed alongside: https://sagebionetworks.jira.com/wiki/display/PLFM/Fixing+sed+on+OSx Otherwise you may have to consider something like Perl, which doesn't change too much at the basic level between versions.

Comment: I have just installed GNU sed via homebrew and will see how I go.  
gsed (GNU sed) 4.2.2

Comment: This worked:  
    /usr/local/bin/gsed -i -e "/^\$dokuwiki_hash =/a \blah" /Volumes/HDD2/Sites/clients/go2humanperformance/install.php

Answer (score 1):

`\n` is not supported as a newline character in the replacement part of the substitute command of regular `sed` (only in `GNU sed`).

For example to prepend a newline to a pattern, instead of

```
sed 's/pattern/\n&/' file
```

use

```
sed 's/pattern/\
&' file
```

The `\` should be the last character on the line.